# My script isn't executing properly on page load

Tags: javascript, html

My script is supposed to be called when the page loads, but something inside of the if statement is not working properly.

I know the script is being called because onload, the alert works. I do not know what is acting up inside the if statement.

```js
    function nameCheck() {
        alert("test");
            if(localstorage.getItem("name" === "undefined") || localstorage.getItem("name" === null)) {
                var name = prompt("Please enter your name");
                localStorage.setItem("name", name);
                location.reload();
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("welcome") = "Hello, " + localStorage.getItem("name");
            }
        }
```

```html
<body onload="nameCheck()">
<h1 id="welcome"></h1>
```

I want the code to check if your name is in localstorage, and if it is, get the element with the id "welcome" and say "Hello, [name]." If it is not in localstorage, I want it to prompt for your name, save it, and reload.

The element with the id "welcome" is staying blank, even when the page reloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as what @Gendarme said above (about `innerHTML`) you are also checking the localStorage values in the wrong way.

For example, you are checking if the "`name`" variable is null as follows:

`localStorage.getItem("name" === null)`

However it should be like this:

`localStorage.getItem("name") === null`

Also the word/term "`localStorage`" in your code (in the first if statement) has a small "s" and it should be a capital "S".

So the full code should be as follows:

```
 function nameCheck() {
    alert("test");
    if(localStorage.getItem("name") === undefined || localStorage.getItem("name") === null) {
        var name = prompt("Please enter your name");
        localStorage.setItem("name", name);
        location.reload();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "Hello, " + localStorage.getItem("name");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Good catch. Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of the element.

```
document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "Hello, " + localStorage.getItem("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Also a slight improvement to @Sarah code above, you don't need to validate if it's undefined or null separately.

You can use:

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("name"))
```

Good find by Sarah about the capital S of the `localStorage`

So, your code should be like:

```
 function nameCheck() {
    alert("test");
    if(!localStorage.getItem("name")) {
        var name = prompt("Please enter your name");
        localStorage.setItem("name", name);
        location.reload();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "Hello, " + localStorage.getItem("name");
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks. Actually i think its better as it was as !localStorage.getItem("name") could return a false positive.

Comment: Good point there. Btw, does the `"undefined"` need to be inside a quote? Isn't it supposed to be similar to `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this `if(localstorage.getItem("name" === "undefined") || localstorage.getItem("name" === null))` , write the code as :

`if(localStorage.getItem("name") == "undefined" || localStorage.getItem("name") == null)`

Since your format of code was wrong in first place its expected not to work. To get key pair value from localStorage you should write it as localStorage.getItem(key).Now, localStorage only supports strings as values, so be careful in using comparison sign as u know `localStorage.getItem(name) === null` will not work so use `localStorage.getItem(name) == null` instead.